# Infinite data load in listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-recyclerview

I have infinite data in json i want to implement in listview/recyclerview with load more in my listview/recyclerview

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "Joy",
    "lastName": "Jones"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "firstName": "Sal",
    "lastName": "Jsdones"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "firstName": "Pedfdter",
    "lastName": "sdfs"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "firstName": "sfsfs",
    "lastName": "gjng"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "firstName": "fgfg",
    "lastName": "dfgg"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "firstName": "fdfgde",
    "lastName": "erwrw"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "firstName": "fsc",
    "lastName": "cscfsd"
}]
```

now i want to add ion-infinite-scroll,but same data can not be show

this is my first app.

Comment: don't get all the data from web service at a time, instead ask them to send records in chunks like 10-20 records at a time. And when you want to fetch data again send them the id of the last record for fetching further records. Also add a check in your recyclerview that when the last item is visible and then call api again

Comment: Yes, He is right.

Answer (score 0):

Read full my sample in github :
[EndlessRecyclerview](https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/EndlessRecyclerview)